# PHP - 2D Array table formatting

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I've got a 2D array of movies with keys which was generated via phpMyAdmin via a MySQL Db.

(Plot cut off from copy pasting)

```
$films = array(
  array('title' => 'Batman Begins','yr' => '2005','genre' => 'Action, Adventure','plot' => 'After training with his mentor, Batman begins his w...')
  array('title' => 'Ted 2','yr' => '2015','genre' => 'Comedy','plot' => 'Newlywed couple Ted and Tami-Lynn want to have a baby, but in order to...')
  array('title' => 'Ted','yr' => '2012','genre' => 'Comedy, Fantasy','plot' => 'As the result of a childhood wish, John Bennett\'s teddy bear, ...')
  array('title' => 'Interstellar','yr' => '2014','genre' => 'Adventure, Sci-Fi','plot' => 'A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in spa...')
);
```

I've also got a foreach loop, to loop through the 2D array and return the results as a table:

```
$out = "";
$out .= "<table>";
foreach($films as $key => $element){
  $out .= "<tr>";
  foreach($element as $subk => $subel){
    $out .= "<td>$subel</td>";
  }
  $out .= "</tr>";
}
$out .="<table>";

echo $out;
```

And from the results I see on the web page, this displays it like this:

Batman Begins     2005      Action, Adventure     After training ...

How would I be able to display the key as the column header? I've tried making another foreach loop inside the main one, but that returned the header like this: `titleyrgenreplottitleyrgenreplot` etc.

How would I be able to properly format it in a table, so headers appear?

Also just a small, quick question: instead of exporting the database from phpMyAdmin as a PHP array, how would I be able to update the PHP/webpage when a change has been made in the MySQL database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you will get your headers:

```
$headers="<thead><tr>";
foreach($films as $key => $element){
   $headers.= "<th>$key</th>";
  }
$headers.= "</tr></thead>";
```

So your code should now look like:

```
$out = "";
$out .= "<tbody>";
$headers="<table><thead><tr>";
foreach($films as $key => $element){
  $headers.= "<th>$key</th>";
  $out .= "<tr>";
  foreach($element as $subk => $subel){
      $out .= "<td>$subel</td>";
  }
  $out .= "</tr>";
}
$out .="</tbody><table>";
$headers.= "</tr></thead>";

echo $headers;
echo $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying fields as header we just have to loop through the keys of 1st sub array and add another row(`<tr>`) with table header(`<th>`) before  loop through the entire result. Generally we display headers only once.

```
 $out = "";
 $out .= "<table>";
 $out .= "<tr>";
 foreach($films[0] as $key => $value)
 {
   $out  .= "<th>".$key."</th>";
 }
 $out .= "</tr>";
 foreach($films as $key => $element){
  $out .= "<tr>";

  foreach($element as $subk => $subel){
   $out .= "<td>$subel</td>";
  }
  $out .= "</tr>";
 }
 $out .="<table>";

 echo $out;
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: As you can see @JayBlanchard. This seems to be pretty straight forward loop question. So I just answered with respect to Inquirer. However I would take your advice and update my answer.

Comment: I understand that it is straightforward, but consider than there will be *n* number of newbies who will not understand what you have done.

Comment: I will make this a point that I explain my each and every answer so that It may be helpful for other too. Thanks @JayBlanchard